# Using same Activity to display different values

Tags: android, android-activity, workflow

I have 2 activities A and B.

- A is the main activity and call B with user information using
  startActivityForResult
- B is the activity  to display user information [and can
  call B with other user information]

A->B[user1]->B[user2]->B[user1]->B[user3]->B[user4]->....

Create new B activity with correct datas is done but the problem is when go back, for example, como back from B[user4] to B[user3] I need restore activity with user3 information and correct view [Selected correct tab,...]

Comment: Just use new instances of activity B. Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to store your data (users) in a **LIFO** (last-in-first-out) [stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) of objects, and when you switch between users you just add/remove the user from the stack and reload your `ActivityB` with the new informations.

Or you can just create a *new instance* of `ActivityB` for each user.